# how to display a percentage in pie chart using apache poi

Tags: java, apache-poi

I'm trying to make a pie chart with apache poi. I want to display the percentage in pie chart like this.

[image]

raw data

[image]

here my code, what did i miss ??

```java
XSSFDrawing drawing = sheet.createDrawingPatriarch();
XSSFClientAnchor anchor = drawing.createAnchor(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 7, 20);

XSSFChart chart = drawing.createChart(anchor);
chart.setTitleText("summary");
chart.setTitleOverlay(true);

XDDFChartLegend legend = chart.getOrAddLegend();
legend.setPosition(LegendPosition.TOP_RIGHT);

XDDFDataSource < String > status = XDDFDataSourcesFactory.fromStringCellRange(sheet,
    new CellRangeAddress(0, 0, 0, 2));

XDDFNumericalDataSource < Double > values = XDDFDataSourcesFactory.fromNumericCellRange(sheet,
    new CellRangeAddress(1, 1, 0, 2));

XDDFChartData data = chart.createData(ChartTypes.PIE3D, null, null);
data.setVaryColors(true);
XDDFChartData.Series series = data.addSeries(status, values);
chart.plot(data);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are missing are the data labels.

Setting data labels for charts is not yet supported by `apche poi` `XDDF` charts up ti ver sion `4.1.2`. So we need using the `ooxml-schemas` classes for this.

Following code generates your wanted chart. It needs `apache poi 4.1.2` and additionally `ooxml-schemas 1.4`.

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import org.apache.poi.ss.util.CellRangeAddress;
import org.apache.poi.xddf.usermodel.chart.*;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.*;

public class PieChart {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    Object[][] data = new Object[][] {
     new Object[] {"A", "B", "C"},
     new Object[] {5d, 10d, 34d}
    };

    try (XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook()) {
      XSSFSheet sheet = wb.createSheet("piechart");

      // create sheet data
      Row row;
      Cell cell;
      for (int rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < 2; rowIndex++) {
        row = sheet.createRow((short) rowIndex);
        for (int colIndex = 0; colIndex < 3; colIndex++) {
          cell = row.createCell((short) colIndex);
          Object cellValue = data[rowIndex][colIndex];
          if (cellValue instanceof String) {
            cell.setCellValue((String)cellValue);
          } else if (cellValue instanceof Double) {
            cell.setCellValue((Double)cellValue);
          }
        }
      }

      // create drawing and anchor
      XSSFDrawing drawing = sheet.createDrawingPatriarch();
      XSSFClientAnchor anchor = drawing.createAnchor(0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 15, 15);

      // create chart
      XSSFChart chart = drawing.createChart(anchor);
      chart.setTitleText("summary");
      chart.setTitleOverlay(false);
      XDDFChartLegend legend = chart.getOrAddLegend();
      legend.setPosition(LegendPosition.TOP);

      XDDFDataSource<String> cat = XDDFDataSourcesFactory.fromStringCellRange(sheet,
          new CellRangeAddress(0, 0, 0, 2));
      XDDFNumericalDataSource<Double> val = XDDFDataSourcesFactory.fromNumericCellRange(sheet,
          new CellRangeAddress(1, 1, 0, 2));

      XDDFChartData chartData = chart.createData(ChartTypes.PIE3D, null, null);
      chartData.setVaryColors(true);
      XDDFChartData.Series series = chartData.addSeries(cat, val);
      chart.plot(chartData);

      // add data labels
      if (!chart.getCTChart().getPlotArea().getPie3DChartArray(0).getSerArray(0).isSetDLbls()) 
        chart.getCTChart().getPlotArea().getPie3DChartArray(0).getSerArray(0).addNewDLbls();
      chart.getCTChart().getPlotArea().getPie3DChartArray(0).getSerArray(0).getDLbls()
        .addNewShowLegendKey().setVal(false);
      chart.getCTChart().getPlotArea().getPie3DChartArray(0).getSerArray(0).getDLbls()
        .addNewShowPercent().setVal(true);
      chart.getCTChart().getPlotArea().getPie3DChartArray(0).getSerArray(0).getDLbls()
        .addNewShowLeaderLines().setVal(false);
      chart.getCTChart().getPlotArea().getPie3DChartArray(0).getSerArray(0).getDLbls()
        .addNewShowVal().setVal(false);
      chart.getCTChart().getPlotArea().getPie3DChartArray(0).getSerArray(0).getDLbls()
        .addNewShowCatName().setVal(false);
      chart.getCTChart().getPlotArea().getPie3DChartArray(0).getSerArray(0).getDLbls()
       .addNewShowSerName().setVal(false);
      chart.getCTChart().getPlotArea().getPie3DChartArray(0).getSerArray(0).getDLbls()
       .addNewShowBubbleSize().setVal(false);

      // do not auto delete the title; is necessary for showing title in Calc
      if (chart.getCTChart().getAutoTitleDeleted() == null) chart.getCTChart().addNewAutoTitleDeleted();
      chart.getCTChart().getAutoTitleDeleted().setVal(false);

      // data point colors
      byte[][] rgb = new byte[][]{
       new byte[] {127, 127, (byte)255},
       new byte[] {(byte)255, 127, 127},
       new byte[] {127, 127, 127}
      };
      for (int p = 0; p < 3; p++) {
        chart.getCTChart().getPlotArea().getPie3DChartArray(0).getSerArray(0).addNewDPt().addNewIdx().setVal(p);
        chart.getCTChart().getPlotArea().getPie3DChartArray(0).getSerArray(0).getDPtArray(p)
          .addNewSpPr().addNewSolidFill().addNewSrgbClr().setVal(rgb[p]);
      }

      // write the output to a file
      try (FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream("ooxml-pie-chart.xlsx")) {
        wb.write(fileOut);
      }
    }
  }
}
```